# Google Scripts difference of dates, and appending rows to separate tabs

Tags: javascript, java, google-apps-script

*******I figured it out. edited the code now it works great! thanks for the feedback*****

im a novice coder, i have a google sheet with borrower information. the first column has the dates that the information was received. the script im writing needs to be able to tell if the information was received within 30 days, 45 days, 30-60 days, 60-90 days and 90+ days then append that row of information to the appropriate tab in the google sheets document. this is what i have so far but it doesn't work.

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zQHmusx0pcHz4EPYcdmrLeJarWI7LFw5fCVfYDsTL_k/edit#gid=0");
var headSS = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pnXax3qv2ALswaLshUz6nXobV9e0W0qOOo_0n16r76Y/edit#gid=0");
var headCopy = headSS.getSheets()[0];
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);
var headRows = headCopy.getDataRange().getValues();
var headRow = headRows[0];

for(var p = 1; p < 6; p++) {
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[p]);
    ss.getDataRange().clear();
    ss.appendRow(headRow);
}

ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);
var dataRange   = ss.getDataRange();
var todayDate   = new Date();
var dateConv    = 1000*60*60*24;
var sheet       = ss.getSheets()[0]; 
var sheet30     = ss.getSheetByName('30day'); 
var sheet45     = ss.getSheetByName('45day'); 
var sheet3060   = ss.getSheetByName('30-60'); 
var sheet6090   = ss.getSheetByName('60-90'); 
var sheet90     = ss.getSheetByName('90+'); 


for ( var i = 0; i < dataRange.getNumRows(); i++){ 



    var range       = sheet.getRange(i+1, 1); 
    var loanDate    = range.getValue();
    var lDate       = Date(range);
    var msBetweenDates = todayDate - loanDate;
    var dateDiff    = msBetweenDates/dateConv;

    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zQHmusx0pcHz4EPYcdmrLeJarWI7LFw5fCVfYDsTL_k/edit#gid=0');
    var sheetToCopy = spreadSheet.getSheets()[0];
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0])
    var rows = sheetToCopy.getDataRange().getValues();
    var row = rows[i];
  if (dateDiff < 31.0){
        sheet30.appendRow(row); 
    }
  if (dateDiff < 46.0){
        sheet45.appendRow(row); 
    }
  if (dateDiff > 30.0 && dateDiff < 61.0){
        sheet3060.appendRow(row);
    }
  if (dateDiff > 60.0 && dateDiff < 91.0){
        sheet6090.appendRow(row);
    }
  if (dateDiff > 89.0){
        sheet90.appendRow(row);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there are lots of issues here, before we can even troubleshoot.  I edited your post to make it easier to read, and moved some things.

1) Don't put variables that don't depend on the loop INSIDE the loop.  That just revalues them over and over, unnecessarily.  I moved some outside the loop.

2) `for(var p = 1; p < 2; p++) {` doesn't loop.  It runs once, with p==1

3) Are you sure `ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[p]);` gets the sheet you want?  Remember, the list indexing starts at 0.

4) So, you clear the data, then get the data range?  Are you sure?

5) A date object is not a number.  You cannot just divide it to get the day.  If you are trying to get the days between dates, you want to subtract the dates first, to get milliseconds, then do the arithmetic:

```
var todayDate   = new Date();
var millisecondsBetweenDates = dateFromSheetField - todayDate;
daysBetweenDates = millisecondsBetweenDates / dateConv;
```

6) Your if-then orderings are messed up.  e.g. in `(dateDiff > 29.0) && (dateDiff < 61.0)`,  `dateDiffs` between 29 and 46 would already have been hit in the previous conditional: `(dateDiff < 46.0)`, so would never get this far.  Same for the next 2.

7) What are you trying to do here:

`var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet.getId());`?

You are essentially just renaming `sheet`

I hope those pointers nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: thank you for the help. basically i want to clear every tab of data except for the first tab. the program needs to check the first column of the first tab and tell if the row is less than 30 days old and if so copy the row to the 30day tab, tell if the row is less than 45 days old and if so copy it to the 45 day tab, between 30-60, 60-90 and 90+ etc. idk if this clarifies anything. im also very new to these forums and im not sure how to show you my updated code... thank you for your patience